# input-group doesn't fit the whole td content in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following web page:

**HTML**

```
<div class="center-both">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/246x105">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x390">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="video-url" type="text" class="form-control" value="some_text">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="copy-clipboard" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-both {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}

.center-both img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

(JSFiddle link -- https://jsfiddle.net/7rkrfj87/2/)

It looks as expected in Firefox:

[image]

But in Chrome `input-group` doesn't fit the whole `td`:

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I force it to fit the whole `td` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `width: 100%` duh!

```
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have checked it in Chrome, Firefox.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fLs7t1v8/**

Comment: Thanks a lot! And why does it happen?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Because of `display: table` and Firefox "incorrectly" inherits, may be?